# Revert to old java policy

Tags: java, applet, policy, java-security

I had overridden java.policy using

```
System.setProperty("java.security.policy","newPolicy.policy");
```

Now I want point to my default java.policy, but it is not working even if I try to give the default policy path, and due to that my applet is also not loading as it referring custom policy but not default policy.

Comment: can you please post your code. So it will be more clear.

Comment: I don't have code as such, but I would like to point to my default java policy which I'm unable to do

Comment: Well, if applets could change the policy while there is an active security manager, it would render the entire concept of a security manager pointless.